# Почему событие срабатывает не правильно?

Tags: reactjs

Имеется вот такой React компонент:

```js
import React from 'react';

import './AppSearch.css'

class AppSearch extends React.Component {

 constructor() {
  super();

  this.state = {
   request: '',
  }

  this.onSearch = (e) => {
   this.setState({
    request: e.target.value,
   })
   console.log(this.state.request);
  }

 }

 render () {
  return(
   <input className='AppSearch' value={this.state.request} onChange={ this.onSearch } placeholder = 'Search parametr' />
  )
  
 }
};

export default AppSearch;
```

По как-то причине событие `onChange` работает не правильно. Не могу разобраться почему.

Функция `onSearch` сначала меняет `request`, а потом только выводит это значение, а получается так, как-будто оно работает наоборот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На скриншоте видно, что я ввел три двойки, а в консоли их только две. С чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 0):

`setState` не меняет состояние сразу (во время исполнения куска в котором он объявлен). Для участка кода после `setState` состояние будет тоже, что и прежде. Вот что нужно сделать в вашем случае:

```
this.onSearch = (e) => {
        let val = e.target.value;
        this.setState({
            request: val
        })
        console.log(val);
    }
```

Думаю, логика понятна.

Answer (score 0):

У `setState` есть `callback`:

```
this.setState({
    request: e.target.value
}, () => {
    console.log(this.state.request)
})
```

Вот так будет правильно работать (ожидаемое вами поведение) :)